# Filter by Last Record from Table for Particular Date that has repeated Item No in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to know how to implement following logic in SQL, I have a table with data in the following format:

```
Date      ItemNo     Price
--------------------------
20160101   101        150
20160101   101        155
20160101   101        140
20160101   102        144
20160101   103        147
20160102   101        150
20160102   101        155
20160102   101        140
20160102   102        144
20160102   103        147
```

so from the above, I want to select all the ItemNo but only to pick the last entry from ItemNo "101" as an example (it can be any ItemNo which has multiple data for same date), so meaning my output table will have the following output:

```
Date      ItemNo     Price
--------------------------
20160101   101        140
20160101   102        144
20160101   103        147
20160102   101        140
20160102   102        144
20160102   103        147
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?!

Comment: is there a primary key or a datetime field that has time in it to understand the in which order the records where added?  Because you can use ROW_NUMBER() as some people suggest but indexes and query optimization will change the order on you and it may not necessarily represent the order in which the records where entered

Comment: also which is it 2008 or 2012?  if both just put 2008 because then you will not get specific 2012 methodology like the nice easy LAST_VALUE() that Kannan shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how do you define 'last item' - based on your data it's not clear why price 160 is the last item for ItemNo 101 and Date 20160101. But if you have some column with 'Time' or 'Id' you can do it like this:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        Date, ItemNo, Price,
        row_number() over(partition by Date, ItemNo order by Time desc) as rn
    from <table>
)
select
    Date, ItemNo, Price
from cte
where
    rn = 1
```

Comment: the data in my table is always in order form, i just want to find a way how to get the last entry of an item that has more than one value...keeping in mind Item Price can change in between and not necessarily to be the highest value: example: first entry is 100$ , second is 200$ and third is 150$

Comment: there're no such a thing as guaranteed order in the sql table. Basically, if you put order one by one into the table you can't rely that you'll receive them in the same order when you select. That's why you need 'order by' clause. There're some gotchas for this, but in general - there's no order

Comment: Thanks for correcting my Info, so with regards to above code... it will only works with ItemNo "101" and in my table there's a chance different ItemNo can have multiple entry for the same date, will the above consider this dynamiicty.

Comment: @3MRAN it works with multiple entries for every ItemNo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LAST_VALUE

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  date,
  itemno,
  LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY date, itemno ORDER BY itemno)
FROM #test
```

[image]

Comment: + 1 except I would note that this is a 2012+ answer and that the order by here should by on a primary key or a time field or something that would indicate which order the records where entered.  With out that just changing columns involved in query could re-order the results or it will simply be exactly LIKE MIN(price) (PARTITIONED BY date) at all times.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the "last" item no, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  If you don't have a unique id, I would suggest something like this:

```
select Date, ItemNo, Price
from t
where itemno <> 101
union all
select Date, ItemNo, Price
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by date, itemno order by itemno) as seqnum
      from t
      where itemno = 101
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you do have a unique id, you can do something like this:

```
select date, itemno, max(price) as price
from t
group by date,
         (case when itemno <> 101 then id end);
```

Admittedly, this will always return the highest price for `itemno`, but that does match some definition of "any".

Comment: the data in my table is always in order form, i just want to find a way how to get the last entry of an item that has more than one value...keeping in mind Item Price can change in between and not necessarily to be the highest value: example: first entry is 100$ , second is 200$ and third is 150$

Comment: @3MRAN . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column explicitly defines it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my Info, so with regards to above code... it will only works with ItemNo "101" and in my table there's a chance different ItemNo can have multiple entry for the same date, will the above consider this dynamiicty.

Comment: @3MRAN . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is asked, and this question is *explicitly* about item 101.  If you have a different question, then ask *another* question.  If you modify this one, you will invalidate the answers of anyone who was tried to help, and invalidated answers draw downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help here... but I have clearly mentioned already " (it can be any ItemNo which has multiple data for same date) "